# Quick Question About IIS 7 Asp.Net Setup

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I have been trying to configure a small website on a Windows Server 2008 running IIS 7. Unfortunately, when trying to load the website I keep getting the error: *Server Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.*

The permissions on the website folder include `read`, `write`, and `execute` for user `ASP.NET v4.0`.  I even clicked "Check names" before adding the user to folder, to make sure that I spelled everything correctly.  But the error continues to show.  Also, I noticed that everything works okay if I add "Users" to the permissions for the folders containing the website, but I don't see why this should be necessary. I only want to give `ASP.NET v4.0` access to the folder.

Some other noteworthy points include that I'm using the `ASP.NET v4.0` application pool, that the managed pipeline is integrated, and that load user profile is set to true.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciated the help.  I'm stumped!

EDIT:  Does it matter that the website is on the d: drive?  I just assumed this wasn't important...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find I always need to give IIS_IUSRS access.

Comment: Thanks Oren.  I tried adding IIS_IUSRS permissions (read, write, and execute) to the websites folder, but it produces the error.  It must be a more specific user group than Users, I guess.

Comment: Okay Oren, you got this one.  You were really close!  The user that I had to grant permissions to was IUSR: http://forums.iis.net/p/1163005/1948756.aspx#1948756

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to use the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to detect which user is actually accessing the file.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190685/how-to-use-process-monitor-to-resolve-an-unauthorizedaccessexception) you'll find an explanation about how to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks for the links!  I tried running ProcMon, but there were too many rows in the window for me to judge which ones corresponded to my hitting the site.  I filtered out everything but internet explorer, and then tried narrowing down the path of the application (not sure if this was the right thing to do, but I picked the path that IE runs from when it's started on the server)...  I think I need more practice with Process Monitor...

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS7 on the server. Highlight the site, and double-click on the Authentication icon in the Security Section. Check that Anonymous Authentication is enabled.

Some troubleshooting links for this particular issue:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902160

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907273

Comment: Did you add full permissions on the site folder for the "NETWORK SERVICE" account? Also, try setting "load user profile" to false - is the some reason you have this set to true?

Comment: @Mr. Chieftan - Sorry for the late response (went to sleep last night...)  Using Network Service didn't seem to have any additional effects.  I also tried the suggestion about setting "load user profile" to false, but to no avail...  I'm going to research this Authentication icon in the security section a little more...

Comment: @Mr. Cheiftan - I just wanted to give you kudos for being on the right track.  It turns out that if I click "Edit" in the right-hand pain while highlighting "Anonymouse Authentication", I can then select ApplicationPoolIdentity instead of using the user IUSR.  This is probably the best way to allow asp.net to authenticate in IIS 7.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Mr. Chieftan - PPS - I can't believe that IUSR was configured in the first place.  What in the world?!?