# Why is my Orchard installation looking for d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\....?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-permissions, orchardcms

I am recieving an error message what appears to be permission related. I can't workout which file needs permissions changing on. What I was also curious about was why the error is looking at paths like

> d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs

Is it trying to call upon an external library elsewhere?

Any help would be great

> > Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7,
>   and the configured application pool
>   identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating.
>   If the application is impersonating
>   via ,
>   the identity will be the anonymous
>   user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or
>   the authenticated request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access
>   is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))]
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32
>   errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) +0
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32
>   errorCode) +49
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.UnmanagedLibraryHelper..ctor(String
>   fileName) +76
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethodsHelper..ctor(String
>   modulePath) +27
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadValidLibrary(String
>   modulePath) +281
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinariesFromPrivateFolder(String
>   privateInstall) +76
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.NativeMethods.LoadNativeBinaries()
>   +225    System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand..ctor()
>   +65
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor,
>   Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis,
>   Boolean fillCache) +98
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache) +241
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type
>   type, Boolean nonPublic) +69
>   NHibernate.Bytecode.ActivatorObjectsFactory.CreateInstance(Type
>   type) +8
>   NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver.CreateCommand()
>   +28    NHibernate.Driver.SqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2
>   settings) +99
>
>   Orchard.Data.Providers.OrchardSqlServerCeDriver.Configure(IDictionary`2
>   settings) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Providers\SqlCeDataServicesProvider.cs:77
>   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2
>   settings) +158
>
> [HibernateException: Could not create
>   the driver from
>   Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver,
>   Orchard.Framework, Version=1.0.20.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.]
>   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2
>   settings) +241
>
>   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.Configure(IDictionary`2
>   settings) +86
>   NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2
>   settings) +351
>
>   NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2
>   properties) +953
>   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings()
>   +17    NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
>   +44    Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.BuildSessionFactory()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:74
>   Orchard.Data.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:52
>   Orchard.Data.SessionLocator.For(Type
>   entityType) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\SessionLocator.cs:29
>   Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Session()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:26    Orchard.Data.Repository`1.get_Table()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:30    Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Fetch(Expression`1
>   predicate) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:126    Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Get(Expression`1
>   predicate) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:91    Orchard.Data.Repository`1.Orchard.Data.IRepository<T>.Get(Expression`1
>   predicate) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Data\Repository.cs:60    Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetDescriptorRecord()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Descriptor\ShellDescriptorManager.cs:52
>   Orchard.Core.Settings.Descriptor.ShellDescriptorManager.GetShellDescriptor()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Settings\Descriptor\ShellDescriptorManager.cs:25
>   Orchard.Environment.ShellBuilders.ShellContextFactory.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings
>   settings) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Environment\ShellBuilders\ShellContextFactory.cs:66
>   Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.CreateShellContext(ShellSettings
>   settings) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:128
>   Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.b__1(ShellSettings
>   settings) in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:100
>   System.Linq.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
>   +85    System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +217
>
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray(IEnumerable`1
>   source) +78
>   Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.BuildCurrent()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:87
>   Orchard.Environment.DefaultOrchardHost.Orchard.Environment.IOrchardHost.Initialize()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard\Environment\DefaultOrchardHost.cs:56
>   Orchard.Web.MvcApplication.Application_Start()
>   in
>   d:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x\src\Orchard.Web\Global.asax.cs:22
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   create the driver from
>   Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver,
>   Orchard.Framework, Version=1.0.20.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9028953
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers) +131
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState
>   state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +194 
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +339 
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +253
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not
>   create the driver from
>   Orchard.Data.Providers.SqlCeDataServicesProvider+OrchardSqlServerCeDriver,
>   Orchard.Framework, Version=1.0.20.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +8950644
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext
>   context) +97
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +256
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: What exactly was the solution to this problem? (If there was any)

Comment: It was a file permissions problem. Afraid I can't remember the permissions I used but I think it was around an exe file that is required

Comment: In my case, the root problem was the machine did not have SQL Server Compact 4.0 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths to `D:\TeamCity\Projects\Orchard-1.x` are a bit of a misdirection, they appear within the [stack trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace.aspx) and more specifically refer to where the project was originally built, not where Orchard is looking for resources.

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is a [Continuous Integration System](http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html) used quite widely in the .NET World.

I can't give you a concrete solution to your problem, you do appear to be correct in your assumption that it is a permissions issue. I would recommend using [process monitor to track down origin of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190685/how-to-use-process-monitor-to-resolve-an-unauthorizedaccessexception/190858#190858).

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar problem](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23654/access-is-denied-while-processing-web-config-with-sql-server-compact) (an MVC 3 site using Sql Server Compact 4.0) with a hoster that runs the Plesk control panel, and I [fixed it](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/23667/12228) by giving "Read/Execute" rights to the the "Plesk IIS WP User" for the \bin folder and all its child objects.

Comment: Thanks! In my case this was exactly what it was, Plesk control panel and all.